# Непонятная ошибка ruby

Tags: ruby

Недавно начал изучать ruby по учебнику, пример от туда

```
lineWidth = 40
str = '--> текст <--'
puts str.ljust  lineWidth
puts str.center lineWidth
puts str.rjust  lineWidth
puts str.ljust (lineWidth/2) + str.rjust (lineWidth/2)
```

выдает ошибку

```
syntax error, unexpected ( arg, expecting end-of-input
...ust (lineWidth/2) + str.rjust (lineWidth/2)
```

Просто интересно с чем это связано, или учебник устарел уже.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995593

Answer (score 0):

Просто удали пробелы между именем метода и круглыми скобками:

```
puts str.ljust(lineWidth/2) + str.rjust(lineWidth/2)
```

На это и указывает ошибка прописывая:
синтаксическая ошибка, неожиданная ( аргумент, ожидающий окончания ввода)